# link tag is removed by ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using Ckeditor in drupal 7.26. I placed HTML Content with link tag in the source of Ckeditor. It removes link tag. I want to send my css file through that html content. How can I add it into the editor.

Comment: Considering the `<link>` tag is only valid inside the `<head>` of a document, and I can't think of a situation where you would be using CKEditor to edit the `<head>`, even if you could solve this, what use would it be other than to make sure your document is invalid?

Comment: Yeah, I Placed link tag in <head> section but it removes Head tags along with <link> tag

Comment: So you're adding a `<head>` section in CKEditor? That's probably the problem. It's not valid to include `<head>` inside `<body>`. It needs to be a direct descendant of `<html>`, which you don't have access to in CKEditor (usually)

Comment: Without head tag also it removes <link> tag

Comment: I think it does not accept <link> tag in <body>

Comment: Correct @Manu, see my first comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Clive said there is almost certainly no situation that CKeditor  can *validly* edit/create an html `head` element. Since `link` *must* be a child of a head element this means that CKEditor cannot create a valid `link` element.

That being said there is a way to add a stylesheet the the CKEditor. You will have to allow JavaScript in whatever filter you are using (**so use with caution**) and then insert a script like this:

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $('head').apend("<link rel='stylesheet' href='my/added/stylesheet.css'>");
  }(jQuery))
</script>
```

Or if you don't want to use jQuery:

```
<script>
  var element = document.createElement("link");
  element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  element.setAttribute("href", "/my/added/stylesheet.css");
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);
</script>
```